# How to make Syntastic search for javac config file in project

Tags: vim, syntastic

I'm using Syntastic with vim and I've added external libraries to its classpath (using `SyntasticJavacEditClasspath`).  This creates a file in the current working directory (which was my project folder).  This is all fine.  However, whenever I restart vim, Syntastic seems to search for the `.syntastic_javac_config file` in the current working directory *only*, and the cwd is, of course, randomly whereever I left it in my last operation.  So it doesn't find the file and I get a bunch of incorrect import errors.  Can Syntastic be told to search the file's parents for the config file?  If not, is there a way of using vim where this typically works?  (I've only been using vim for a couple of months so I might be clueless.)

Comment: What exact command did you use and where did you put it?

Comment: What command did I use to add to the classpath?  I used `SyntasticJavacEditClasspath` while my cwd was at my project root (this is java so thats an arbitrary number of folders up from the source files).  The .syntastic_javac_config file ends up in project root, which is presumably where I would want it as the classpath should be shared by all files in the project (including, say, tests in the test folder).

Comment: It sounds like you change your working directory too often. Unless you really need to change it for some unspecified reason, the working directory should always be the root of your project. Anyway, if you have a problem with a particular plugin your best bet is to use its issue tracker.

Comment: What if I open two projects (which is the common case for me) or do file-system operations like moves/renames in vim?  Your recommendation to use the Syntastic bug system is probably my best bet.

Comment: Open your two projects in two Vim instances and do your filesystem operations outside of Vim.

Comment: OK, thanks for the recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the official manual](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic#faqconfig), the snippet should solve the problem. Put it in your `.vimrc`, change the `javascript`, `jscs`, etc. to required values

```
function! FindConfig(prefix, what, where)
    let cfg = findfile(a:what, escape(a:where, ' ') . ';')
    return cfg !=# '' ? ' ' . a:prefix . ' ' . shellescape(cfg) : ''
endfunction

autocmd FileType javascript let b:syntastic_javascript_jscs_args =
    \ get(g:, 'syntastic_javascript_jscs_args', '') .
    \ FindConfig('-c', '.jscs', expand('<afile>:p:h', 1))
```